# How to get access token for creating dataset in Power BI through REST API from Rails APP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, powerbi, office365-restapi

Currently I have only *client_id* and *client_secret* ,what other parameter do I need for creating dataset

Comment: Hi @t s, did you manage to find out? I'm struggling with this too.

Comment: @fro_oo  check my answer hope it will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got this.  First of all we have to connect our Azure AD and power BI application.

```
def index
  update_token
  if session['access_token']

  redirect_to YOUR_ACTION
  else
    client = get_client
    a = client.auth_code.authorize_url(:client_id => CLIENT_ID, :resource => RESOURCE_ID, :redirect_uri => REDIRECT_URI)
    redirect_to(a) 
  end
end

def callback
  begin
    @code = params[:code]
    client = get_client
    token = client.auth_code.get_token(@code, :redirect_uri => REDIRECT_URI, )
    session['access_token'] = token.token
    if token.token.present?
     YOUR_ACTION
    end
  end
end

def update_token
  token = session['access_token']
  refresh_token = session['refresh_token']

  expire_at = session['expire_at']
  @access_token = OAuth2::AccessToken.from_hash(get_client, { :access_token => token, :refresh_token =>  refresh_token, :expire_at => expire_at, :header_format => 'Bearer %s' } )

  if @access_token.expired?

   @access_token = @access_token.refresh!;
   session['access_token'] = @access_token.token
   session['refresh_token'] = @access_token.refresh_token
   session['expire_at'] = @access_token.expire_at  
   session['instance_url']  = @access_token.params['instance_url']
  end
end

def get_client
  client = OAuth2::Client.new(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, :site => AUTHORITY, :authorize_url =>  AUTHORIZE_URL, :token_url => TOKEN_URL )
  client
end

def azure
  callback
end
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing! I use the same piece of code from a gist I've found. I'm mostly strugling with the constants: RESOURCE_ID, REDIRECT_URI, AUTHORITY, AUTHORIZE_URL, TOKEN_URL. I don't know where I must configure those (Azure? PowerBI?) (also.. there's 2 CLIENT_ID and 2 CLIENT_SECRET... one from powerbi and one from Azure? https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-authenticate-a-web-app/ )

Comment: Oh, I have a question for you: Is it possible to call the PowerBI API and authenticate without the end user having also to identify?

Comment: you don't need the power BI client_ID and client_secret .use this (https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-admin-free-with-custom-azure-directory/) . AUTHORITY - "https://login.windows.net" and use your App End points for AUTHORIZE_URL and TOKEN_URL. @fro_oo

Answer (score 0):

To succeed I had to forgot everything I had read before... and start again with this:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/power-bi-embedded-iframe/

ON AZURE PORTAL
Create Power BI workspace collection, and get access key (Provisioning)

GET A PBIX
From Power BI Desktop or a sample file

WITH A CLI
(must use that one : https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Cli )
Create a Power BI workspace
Import .pbix file into the workspace
Get report id

IN MY RAILS APP
(using https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt )
Embed the report into the web page

I can't tell about the many bugs encountered, or the signup/login problems with Azure... it was really painful to get there.

Cheers everyone.

Comment: Hey did you know how can we run a cron task for Power BI ? like in my current code it redirect to Azure portal and requires username and passsword but I want to run it from cron rake task . @fro_oo